# How to stub mysql query using some mock data and mocha in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, stub

My requirement is to use stubbing in unit testing script to bypass some actual mysql query using a mock data. I'm using mocha testing framework and chai. I don't know how to use mock data to bypass the mysql query.

I tried with some testing variable and if the variable is true i'm just bypassing the mysql query with predefined mock data. But that's not a proper proceedure. So can you please explain me how to use sinon stub to overcome mysql using mock data.

```
let query_response = await sequelize.query("select * from `" + table_name + "` where email='" + data.user + "' and name = '" + name + "' " + pre_name + ";", {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        });
```

In unit testing i need to bypass this query and give response using some mock data. The response should be like this,

```
[ { id: '3',
    xyz_id: 'Z1455264',
    vir_id: '264_3',
    name: 'XYZ',
    pre_name: 'abc',
    value: 1 },
  { id: '32',
    xyz_id: 'Z1455dd264',
    vir_id: '26s4_3',
    name: 'XYZQ',
    pre_name: 'abdc',
    value: 1 }];
```

Comment: I am sure you have a good reason for not just installing a little mysql server and giving it a little bit of data that will satisfy your SQL statement (2 simple rows = approx 30 seconds to create and populate a table), but I think you need to tell us what it is. Stubs are usually put in place to temporarily replace complex processing, which surely this isn't.

Comment: @MandyShaw I know the reason why i didn't installed mysql server. For testing it's not necessory. I like to bypass the mysql queries. That's why i didn't installed. Using mock data predefining something and bypassing also a part of stubbing. I know what is stubbing. Thanks

Comment: Fine - I was just surprised that you were in an environment that didn't need its database on a regular basis! Good for me to be challenged ... that's why I come on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways (dependency injection, runtime module replacement, etc) to do it and a bunch of libraries to help you. It's up to the level of abstraction you have and how neat you want it. The quick and dirty way is to use something like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) and a mocking library like [testdouble](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js).

With your *sut.js* (the module/system you will be testing), you would have:

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')

// ...

exports.doSomething = async function () {
  await sequelize.query("select * from `" + table_name + "` where email='" + data.user + "' and name = '" + name + "' " + pre_name + ";", {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
  })
}
```

And in your test you could do the following (agnostic to the testing framework):

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
const td = require('testdouble')
const sequelize = require('sequelize')

const query = td.function()
const sut = proxyquire('/path/to/your/sut.js', { 'sequelize': { query } })

const expected = [{
  id: '3',
  xyz_id: 'Z1455264',
  vir_id: '264_3',
  name: 'XYZ',
  pre_name: 'abc',
  value: 1
}, {
  id: '32',
  xyz_id: 'Z1455dd264',
  vir_id: '26s4_3',
  name: 'XYZQ',
  pre_name: 'abdc',
  value: 1
}];

td.when(query("select * from `<the_table_name>` where email='<the_email>'...", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })).thenResolve(expected);

// assert whatever you need from sut.doSomething()
```

Comment: You might even ditch proxyquire altogether, since testdouble also supports [module replacement](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js#specifying-a-custom-replacement).